# Click on link in wordpress menu and it redirects to specific section of another page

Tags: wordpress, menu, redirect

I want to go on specific section of page after click on wordpress menu link.In my wordpress menu I want to put link in "get started".
I have tried to add this http://localadvertisingthatworks.com/test/#my_site but it redirect in wrong section

1.In page.php:I want to redirect at this section at id="my_site"

```
<section class="forecourtsWrapper" id="my_site">
<a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/adnozzles/">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" >
      <h2>Exclusive UK license for petrol pump advertising</h2></a>
      <div class="cf" >
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-4"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/forecourts-img1.png"  alt=""/> </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-8">
          <div class="typesFC cf" >
            <ul>
              <li>
                <h3>Supermarket</h3>
                Tesco, Sainsburyâ€™s<br/>
                and Morrisons </li>
              <li>
                <h3>Roadside</h3>
                BP, Esso, Texaco, Murco,<br/>
                Jet and others </li>
              <li>
                <h3>Motorway</h3>
                Moto, Road Chef and<br/>
                Welcome Break </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="petrolLogos" id="site_finder" >
            <ul>
              <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/petrol-logo1.png"  alt=""/></li>
              <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/petrol-logo2.png"  alt=""/></li>
              <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/petrol-logo3.png"  alt=""/></li>
              <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/petrol-logo4.png"  alt=""/></li>
              <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/petrol-logo5.png"  alt=""/></li>
              <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/petrol-logo6.png"  alt=""/></li>
              <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/petrol-logo7.png"  alt=""/></li>
              <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/petrol-logo8.png"  alt=""/></li>
              <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/petrol-logo9.png"  alt=""/></li>
              <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/petrol-logo10.png"  alt=""/></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add anchor tags and you'll be good.

```
<a href="http://localadvertisingthatworks.com/test#my_site">Link</a>

<a name="my_site>Anchor</a>
```

[Helpful site](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm)

Comment: I have to remove  <section class="forecourtsWrapper" id="my_site">?

Comment: Nope, it's not related to the anchor link. "ID" is not where the anchor goes to. It goes to a link like `<a name="my_site"></a>`. See the reference I posted.

Comment: I have removed / from the link.But when I am trying to reload the page it takes / automatically in the link

Comment: I have checked it.It's working only in chrome not in firefox and ie.

Comment: Is there any solution for that?

Comment: What's happening in those browsers? It's going to the page but not down the page? Maybe make a new question with the browser-specific problem.

Comment: Is there any jquery code to scroll the page for particular URL.?my URL is:http://localadvertisingthatworks.com/test#my_site

Answer (score 2):

just put `<a name="my_site"></a>` above `<section>` tag like this

```
<a name="my_site"></a>
<section class="forecourtsWrapper" id="my_site">
```

**No change in the link provided or in URL**